# autoit3 _FileListToArray returns file order different than shown in Windows folder

Tags: autoit

How can I return a list of file names in a folder in the same order as shown in Windows with AutoIt3?

Folder content as shown in Windows Explorer

```
_02_02_2007 12_37_45 PM.bin

1D22WP101.bin

1D23DWTB2.bin

1secrate1 Thu Feb 21 2008 021849 PM.bin

02_02_2007 12_37_45 PM.bin

2L9SS1.BIN

3L14SS1.BIN
```

When using

```
_FileListToArray($sDirectory, "*.bin")
```

I get a different sequence for two files which contain underscores (marked with ****)

```
7

****02_02_2007 12_37_45 PM.bin****

1D22WP101.bin

1D23DWTB2.bin

1secrate1 Thu Feb 21 2008 021849 PM.bin

2L9SS1.BIN

3L14SS1.BIN

****_02_02_2007 12_37_45 PM.bin****
```

I've tried sorting with _FileListToArrayRec which changes the order but still does not match Windows

```
_FileListToArrayRec($sDirectory, "*.bin", $FLTAR_FILES, $FLTAR_NORECUR, $FLTAR_SORT)


7

****_02_02_2007 12_37_45 PM.bin****

****02_02_2007 12_37_45 PM.bin****

1D22WP101.bin

1D23DWTB2.bin

1secrate1 Thu Feb 21 2008 021849 PM.bin

2L9SS1.BIN

3L14SS1.BIN
```

Can anybody help how to return a list of file names in AutoIt3 that matches the order seen in Windows?

Thanks for your help!

David

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [_ArraySort()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArraySort.htm) function? In my case it helps :)

Comment: Yes, tried that. Unfortunately, it gives me the same result as in the last example in my original post using the ordering with _FileListToArrayRec().